# ZF2 Form\Element\MultiCheckbox: how to get each item on a new line?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I've been Googling this to no avail. I have a multi-checkbox form element in one of my forms. Here's the code I used to create it:

```
$this->add(array (
    'name' => 'thingyId',
    'type' => 'MultiCheckbox',
    'options' => array (
        'value_options' => $thingyArray,
    )
));
```

In my view script, I have this:

```
<?= $this->formRow($form->get('thingyId')); ?>
```

The form element shows up fine, but all of the checkboxes are on a single line. How do I get it so that each checkbox is on a new line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you view this [link](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/b2a553665ed09242ad72529ab308f585f12b1bcf/src/View/Helper/FormRow.php#L89), you can see that the fourth argument is partial. So, you can use many ways to accomplish the task.

**Method 1:**

```
echo $this->formRow($element, null, null, 'template-file');
```

Now, create a  template file named as `template-file.phtml` to render the element however you like.

```
//template-file.phtml
<span><?php echo $label; ?></span><br/>
<?php foreach ($element->getValueOptions() as $key => $value): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $element->getName() ?>[]" value="<?php echo      $value; ?>">
    <span><?php echo $key; ?></span><br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Method 2**

Create your own view helper by extending the default helper.

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

class MyFormRow extends \Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRow
{
       /**
        * @var string
        */
       protected $partial = 'template-file';
}
```

Now, inform our application about our new helper in your module,

```
namespace Application;

class Module 
{
    public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'invokables' => array(
               'myFormRow' => 'Application\View\Helper\MyFormRow'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Lastly use the helper:

```
echo $this->myFormRow($element);
```

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is, is there not some way to have each item appear on a separate line automatically like it did in ZF1? If you check the tutorial at http://bit.ly/1nCGmmG, you'll see that the form on this page has all the checkbox items on separate lines, and he didn't have to create a custom view helper to do it. So what am I missing? This seems like a lot of trouble to go through to do something that should be much simpler.

Comment: Thanks. Dumb question: I'm actually putting this into a separate module that I call CustomFormView. I've registered the new view and whatnot without any problem. The only question I have is where to put the partial file. I put it in module\CustomFormView\view\custom-form-view\multi-checkbox-element.phtml, but the application can't find it. Which directory should I save it to?

Comment: I think you should read about view template path stack and template maps. For example, if `view` is your template path stack, then create `multi-checkbox-element.phtml` under that directory. Alternatively, you can also define template map for the template

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when I was having this issue myself. The code that was being used was the following:

```
<?php
$oMultiCheckboxField = $oForm->get('multicheckboxelement');
echo $this->formMultiCheckbox($oMultiCheckboxField);
?>
```

The only additional parameter you could pass to the formMultiCheckbox view helper was whether to append or prepend the label.

How I eventually chose to solve this is with the following code:

```
<?php
$oMultiCheckboxField = $oForm->get('multicheckboxelement');
$oMultiCheckboxViewHelper = new \Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormMultiCheckbox();
$oMultiCheckboxViewHelper->setSeparator('<hr>');
echo $oMultiCheckboxViewHelper->render($oMultiCheckboxField);
?>
```

From what I recall, ZF1 had the option to set the separator (I clearly remember this at least for radio buttons). Why there isn't a clearer way to do this in ZF2 is a bit puzzling. If there are better ways to do this, I would certainly like to know about it.